# How to make the cell component handle the cell onmouse event?

Tags: angular, typescript

[It](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vda1gg) is my source code.

Currently, the onmouseover event handler is resided in app.component.ts.
Is it possible to move the onmouseover event handler into the shift-cell.component.ts?

If not, how the handler knows which cell is mouse over?

Comment: You can use a directive instead of a component for your shift cell, and in your say yes, you can pass the stand attribute.

Comment: You can get the cell if you pass $event to the sayYes function as parameter and then get it with event.target

Template:
`td sayYes($event)`
Your component:
`sayYes(event) { alert(event.target.textContent) }`

Comment: @ocheriaf can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icbg8g). With that, you send the stand to the sayYes methods so you can know which is the target. 
If you want to use a shift cell, instead of using a component, you can use an [attribute directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)